# Assigning a value from a passed Spring Boot model to a javascript value

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing a Java Spring project using Timeleaf.

Here's my `MainController`:

```
package com.amo.lab2.controller;

import com.amo.lab2.utils.CountingSort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/form")
    public String form() {
        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/processSorting")
    public String doSorting(@RequestParam("array") String array, Model model) {

        // some logic
        CountingSort countingSort = new CountingSort(intArray);
        model.addAttribute("countingSort", countingSort);
        return "chart";
    }
}
```

Here's part of `chart.html`:

```
<body>
<div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script>

  var xValues = *there should be value countingSort.xValues*;
  var yValues = *there should be value countingSort.yValues*;

  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  // creating a dependency graph

</script>
</body>
```

Is there any way I can assign the variables `xValues` and `yValues` the values from `countingSort` that I passed through the model?

I tried to write

```
var xValues = [${countingSort.xValues}];
var yValues = [${countingSort.yValues}];
```

But it obviously didn't work. I don't even have options on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Thymeleaf, you have to do something extra to access your model variables from within a script section.

Versions of Thymeleaf prior to 3:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

   var xValues = /*[[${countingSort.xValues}]]*/;
   var yValues = /*[[${countingSort.yValues}]]*/;

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

If you're using Thymeleaf 3:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
   var xValues = [[${countingSort.yValues}]];
</script>
```

Refer to this for more details.
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-inlining